# How to get available serial ports in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, window

I am looking for API which can get the list of serial ports in UWP app. 
As System.IO.Ports is not available for UWP, can you suggest any alternative of the below code.

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

Comment: Have you looked this issue on github? https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23294 It seems they have not implemented it yet.

Answer (score 5):

First add this items in **Package.appxmanifest** in your ptoject, to do that right click on Package.appxmanifest and choose **View Code** in Capabilities tag:

```
 <DeviceCapability Name="serialCommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

After that get all serial device connected to your pc and check **PortName**.

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
List<string> portNamesList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in deviceCollection)
{
     var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(item.Id);
     var portName = serialDevice.PortName;
     portNamesList.Add(portName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting 'The semaphore timeout period has expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070079)' execption while calling SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(item.Id), also added capabilities in App manifest.

Comment: On using your code,
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Stack Strace
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(String aqsFilter)

This exception occurs 2-3 times on calling FindAllAsync method again and again, after few trials I get list of ports available.

How to solve this to get list of port on first time executing FindAllAsync method?

Comment: @Dishant Did you got any solution on your Error -  'The semaphore timeout period has expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070079)' ??

In order to get list of COM Port Names, I used this code and I am facing this error. Please give your suggestions, how you resolved this error? Or any alternative solution you worked for and successfully worked without errors?

Comment: @xyzWty, Dishant:  This error slows down the enumeration process quite a bit, and it can happen several times.  It is a port specific issue to the machine the code is running on.  To fix the issue, add an error handler and inspect the item.IDs that throw the error.  For example, a device with an ID like "\\?\BTHENUM#{...}" tells you off the bat that it is a Bluetooth VSP causing the timeout.  You might delete a no-longer used Bluetooth printer under Settings/Printers & Scanners to clear it up.  Otherwise, the ID should give you clues to track down the problem serial driver in Device Manager.

Comment: The above method does not work for all devices.  In my case, I am trying to enumerate the COM ports on a Panasonic FZ-M1 Toughbook.  The "await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync (ID)" returns null even though port.ID points to the correct entry in the registry.  Instead, the port.Name = "DESKTOP-QR####" is returned instead of "COM##".  Probably an architectural issue with the Panasonic, but this method fails nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

An addition for the code presented by @Parsa Karami:

If you try to open the serial port after executing the code it will throw a System.IO.IOException. So, I suggest you adding the Dispose() calling after getting the port name.

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
List<string> portNamesList = new List<string>();
foreach (var result in deviceCollection)
{
    var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(result.Id);
    var portName = serialDevice.PortName;
    serialDevice.Dispose(); // Addition
    portNamesList.Add(portName);
}
```