# RS232 via USB with UnoPlatform and C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, uno-platform

i want to control my power amplifier for my music box with my Raspberry pi 4 and a Uno GUI.
this device has a subd9 socket using rs232 serial communication protocol.
i use a usb to serial converter cable and want to use the raspberrys USB port for this.

the command i need to send is hex and looks like ´
02 00 00 00 01 03

i searched for solutions but i wasn't able to find something suitable.
Does anyone have an idea how i can achieve that?

Thank you for any help

Comment: I think you mix up a few things here. System.IO.Ports is the library for serial port communication in C#. This has nothing to do with the GUI technique you want to use (since an rs232 communication is not Ui-specific). And GTK is the C/C++ desktop API for Linux, which you don't have to care about if you use uno.

Comment: do i? To programm and debug i use my windows laptop. when iam adding the Serial.IO.Port using diretive into my code it shows, that this is avaiable for the UWP Header but not for the other 7 headers including the GTK header which is the one i need to run uno on Raspbian.

Comment: That confuses me. I haven't used uno before, but many similar frameworks, and I don't understand why that would imply a dependency on System.IO.Ports. Can you give the exact error message you get?

Comment: hm okay if this confuses i edit my question a bit

Comment: A Q&D solution: if I wanted to transmit a binary string, I would create a binary file using a binary/hex editor with the required byte values.  Then I'd use `minicom` to send that ("ascii") file.

Comment: SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
            byte[] buffer = {02, 00, 00, 00, 01, 03};
            port.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Comment: @sawdust do you have a guide as referenc? jdweng that dosnt work. it shows a error message saying that the namespace couldnt be found. if i add the using directive System.IO.Ports another error message comes up saying that "SerialPorts" couldnt be found in the namespace System.IO.Ports  Version=0.0.0.0. do you have a solution?

Comment: @JZ2000 Please add the System.IO.Ports nuget to your project, and give the exact error message you get when you do that.

Comment: @pmf i took some pictures. Please look in the Answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have installed V5.0.1 of system.io.ports with no errors. I addet Using System.IO.ports to my Mainpage.cs. and in intelisence a warning appears (picture)

[image]

Sry that it is German,

Nicht verfügbar = not available
verfügbar = available

when i add the code example from jdweng this comes up (picture 2)
[image]

it says:
Error CS1069 The type name "SerialPort" could not be found in the Namespace System.IO.Ports. This type was forwarded to Assembly System.IO.Ports, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51. You should add a reference to the assembly.    Test.Skia.Gtk C:"Users"User-source-repos-Test-Test-Test.Shared-MainPage.xaml.cs 54 Active

Edit 26.05.2021 15:20
I installed the Nuget package on every Header in my Projekt and now alle errors are gone. But now when i try to send jdweng i trhows an exeption:

[image]

Comment: You need to insert a `port.Open()` after the constructor. And use a different constructor, the one with zero arguments always opens COM1, with some arbitrary baudrate, which is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @pmf i inserted   port.PortName = "COM4";
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.Open(); but now i get a exeption  saing "Too many posts were made to a semaphore"

Comment: You do have weird issues ;-)... I don't know what _that_ now means. Where does this happen? Are you trying to execute the code in a loop (without proper disposal)?

Comment: @PMF i will make a Answer with a total desription of my setup

Comment: You should edit your answer (or better yet, the question) instead of create new ones.

Comment: @PMF After it work i will delete all obsolete Answers and make a summary okay?

Answer (score 0):

So here a complete description what i have dont:

1. New Projekt with Cross Plattform App (UNO Framework) template.
2. Deleted all header exept for Gtk and Uwp for simplicity
3. made a one button on mainpage
   [image]
4. inluded this code on button click event
   [image]
5. Startet it and then that happened:
   [image]

Comment: You may want to edit your original question instead of posting new answers.

You are hitting a permissions issues in UWP applications, which has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495093/how-to-get-available-serial-ports-in-uwp